# PySpark add Json to datataframe from another table

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a product master table and I need to add other columns with json that I am going to get from other tables.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
columns = ["product","description"]
data = [("Product 1", "Des 1"), ("Product 2", "Des 2")]
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(columns)
```

```
\+----------+-----------+
|  product|description|
\+----------+-----------+
|Product 1|      Des 1|
|Product 2|      Des 2|
\+----------+-----------+
```

For example, one of the tables that I have to join are the attributes of a product, which are in another table of the database.

```
columns = ["product", "attribute_id","value"]
data = [("Product 1", "1", "value"), ("Product 1", "2","value"),("Product 2", "3", "value"), ("Product 2", "4","value") ]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df_a = rdd.toDF(columns)
```

```
\+----------+------------+-----+
|  product|attribute_id|value|
\+----------+------------+-----+
|Product 1|           1|value|
|Product 1|           2|value|
|Product 2|           3|value|
|Product 2|           4|value|
\+----------+------------+-----+
```

```
df_a.toJSON().collect()
```

```
['{"product":"Product 1","attribute_id":"1","value":"value"}',
'{"product":"Product 1","attribute_id":"2","value":"value"}',
'{"product":"Product 2","attribute_id":"3","value":"value"}',
'{"product":"Product 2","attribute_id":"4","value":"value"}']
```

I have found that the to_json function exists but I don't know if it could be used for what I need, which is to take all the attributes of a product, convert them to json and add them to a column of the first product dataframe

I need to get a result like the following but I can't find how to do it.

```
\+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|product  |description|attributes                                                                  |
\+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Product 1|Des 1      |[{'attribute_id':'1','value':'value'}, {'attribute_id':'2','value':'value'}]|
|Product 2|Des 2      |[{'attribute_id':'3','value':'value'}, {'attribute_id':'4','value':'value'}]|
\+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this with pyspark?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clean up your data/code?  code has `producto` and data has `product` or other way around.  Also please remove "\".